# jQuery Select Combo for Location

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know of a place that has a demo of a `<select>` element that has location then once you select the location, another `<select>` box pops up and you see the region and then once you hit the region, another `<select>` box pops up and you see the town...

Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [Chained Selects](http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects) plugin, or if that doesn't work try searching for "[chaining select boxes](http://www.google.com/#q=chaining+select+boxes)" on Google.